# Map operator. Different function types and accessor

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

i have recently updated Firebase and AngularFire2 in my Ionic project

Versions:

- Firebase: 5.0.3
- AngularFire2: 5.0.0-rc.10
- rxjs 6.2.0

now I tried to upgrade the project from the regular map to pipe using the migration guide:
[Migration guide AngularFire2 version5](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)

But if i use exact the same example for the following code block:

```
    ///my code
    let dataBaseCollection = this.store.collection('items').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => 
    actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
    )
    ).subscribe(items => {
       return items.map(item => item.key);
   });

    ///example

    afDb.list('items').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => 
      actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
    )
  )
```

I get the following exceptions:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction, Observable<{ const: string; return: any; }[]>>'.
>
> Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>
> Property 'source' is protected in type 'Observable' but public in type 'Observable'.

I already tried the two different operator from rxjs

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code seems different from the example. In the example `pipe()` is followed with `.subscribe()` where the return is located.

Comment: Good that you mentioned it. I also tried this just to be sure. But I still get the same error. I will quickly edit my code to be more like the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it running.

I do not have a real clue, what the actual problem was. But I completely deleted my local repository and get all files new.

Then I reinstalled all NPM files. Somewhere in this area was my problem. I would guess, that any of my npm packages was the problem.

Im sorry, that I can not clarify the issue more. Maybe someone else will have the same Problem in the future and can add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is the issue, but a few observations:

`let dataBaseCollection` is receiving a `Subscription` from `.subscribe` and not the items. You cannot return inside the `subscribe`, so your code should be just this:

```
let dataBaseCollection = this.store.collection('items').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() })))
)
```

If you want to map only the keys then just do:

```
let dataBaseCollection = this.store.collection('items').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => a.key))
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. That was my first approach before I edit my example in order to be more equal to the example given by the Documents.  But this is not fixing the issue with the map operator itself. Basically it doesn't matter what is in databaseCollection as long as I get the Call running.